# Change Jinja2 include on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2

Is there a way to switch an Jinja2 `include` block with a different `include` through a Javascript onclick event?  I have two tabs that onclick, switch back and forth between different content.  Is there a better way to implement this with Jinja?

Update to question:  Is there also a way to load a specific `include` based upon a stored cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Jinja is not running in the client.

Normally you'd implement that by having both blocks on the page at all times and using `JavaScript` to show/hide them independently so only one shows.

For your second question (cookies), yes it is possible if you were to pass in the cookies from the framework that is rendering its pages with jinja you can do a conditional around the `include` based on that value, like such:

```
{% if cookievalue == "somevalue" %}
    {% include "somefile.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% include "otherfile.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

How you pass `cookievalue` to jinja depends on the framework you are using.

Comment: How would you access the cookie in the conditional?

Comment: @Hubrid, you could pass the value of the cookie to jinja from the framework you are using and use that in the if/else :)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't exactly understand, at least syntactically, how to do that.  Could you link me to an example or provide a code snippet?